# How To Programmatically Add OpenID Users To Plone Site

Tags: plone

I need to give roles (including the Member role), memberdata, and user folders to certain OpenID users *before* they first log in to my Plone site. That is, I need to programmatically add OpenID users to my Plone site. portal_registration.addMember cannot add an OpenID user. plone.openid has its own PAS plugin which does not create member objects. What do I do that is replicable in a setuphandler? The usual way to do this is to manually log in the OpenID user, then add roles, memberdata, and sharing *after* the login. Howwever, that user story is not programmatically replicable.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that should matter is the user id generated for each user. It should be possible to just create regular members beforehand with user ids matching the open id identity urls, assing them roles and then use openid (only) as an alternative authentication method for those users.

**Update:** As Chris commented below, it's not possible to add users with URL as their id through Plone UI, but they must be created directly into PAS users folder through ZMI (Zope Management Interface).

Comment: Let's say I have ServiceX with preconfigured user accounts (app-specific privileges and view access rights in place). What is the username/openid_key/whatever I should ask users send me? Then I link preconfigured service account to that OpenID account. Say users use Google or Yahoo OpenID provider? Do OpenID providers return email address so I could link preconfigured account?

Comment: I'm afraid that the answer is no. The current default OpenID-implementation in Plone simply assigns the OpenID identity url as userid. And that url may not contain email address and is different for each provider. To support that, plone.openid should be upgraded to support OpenID Attribute Exchange extension.

Comment: I had tried creating members from the OpenID URLs but URLs contain characters which are not valid in userids. As said in the question, portal_registration.addMember would not take a URL for a userid. I appreciate someone finally answering. But not finding an answer while I was working on the application requiring this two years ago, I abandoned using plone.openid and am now at a different job. It's all moot as OpenID is dead, the OpenID provider we were using collapsed, and the upcoming plone.login will support OAuth. How it will tie OAuth auths to member objects is another matter, however.